# Value from client.get() is "true" instead of the real value

Tags: node.js, redis, nowjs-sockets

I am using nowjs and node_redis. I am trying to create something very simple. But so far, the tutorial have left me blank because they only do console.log().

```
//REDIS
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error "+ err);
});

client.set("card", "apple");

everyone.now.signalShowRedisCard = function() {
    nowjs.getGroup(this.now.room).now.receiveShowRedisCard(client.get("card").toString());
}
```

In my client side:

```
now.receiveShowRedisCard = function(card_id) {
    alert("redis card: "+card_id);
}
```

The alert only gives out "true" - I was expecting to get the value of the key "card" which is "apple".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are trying to use an async library in a sync way. This is the right way:

```
//REDIS
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error "+ err);
});

client.set("card", "apple", function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

everyone.now.signalShowRedisCard = function() {
    var self = this;
    client.get("card", function (err, res) {
        nowjs.getGroup(self.now.room).now.receiveShowRedisCard(res);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

One option is to use Bluebird to turn Redis callbacks into promises. Then you can use it with `.then()` or `async/await`.

```
import redis from 'redis'
import bluebird from 'bluebird'

bluebird.promisifyAll(redis)
const client = redis.createClient()

await client.set("myKey", "my value")
const value = await client.getAsync("myKey")
```

Notice your methods should have `Async` appened to them.

Comment: Can you export the client to another module for use? I am trying to export it and it still returns `true` for queries.

Answer (score 4):

## Use Async Redis

`npm i async-redis --save`

```
const asyncRedis = require("async-redis");    
const client = asyncRedis.createClient(); 

await client.set("string key", "string val");
const value = await client.get("string key");

console.log(value);

await client.flushall("string key");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a function provided by node_redis library
`const getAsync = promisify(client.get).bind(client);`
and use this to get values from redis as follows
`const value = await getAsync(key)`